# Where can i find my flathub installation (5.1 hera)

Tags: release-hera

i installed gnome games via sideload and it obviously is installed because i could start it once but cannot find it now in my system.
On the other hand I'd like to know, how to deinstall it, wen i cant' find it in the AppCenter "installed" list.

Thanks in advance!
Jo

Answer (score 0):

ok, seems that a simple restart solved the issue. Unfortunately Gnome Games doesn't support Amiga emulation, yet so i have to be patient and use something else instead.